# RPi set to boot to TFT. TFT not working so how do I get back to HDMI?

Tags: boot-issues

I changed my /dev/fb(0) to /dev/fb(1) to use my TFT screen. 
My TfT screen is still blank but how do I get back to HDMI so I can edit it?

Comment: This is to broad and don't have any information that could lead to a answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a solution so I formatted the SD card and reinstalled Rasbian.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

You could have created a file called "ssh" in the boot partition (by putting the SD card in another pc) and then connect to it through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to connect to your pi via ssh. Its enabled as standard. I would always make sure I have that working before messing with video, mouse, keyboard settings. I recommend superputty on windows